# Given three fixed elements, make them render in a specific order

Tags: css, css-position

If I have three divs, each with fixed position. How can I get `.inner` to appear above the `.overlay`?

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="inner">The inner container</div>
</div>
<div class="overlay"></div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    background: red;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
}
.inner {
    z-index: 3;
    position: fixed;
    margin-top: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    background: yellow;
    height: 30px;
}
.overlay {
    z-index: 2;
    position: fixed;
    background: blue;
    opacity: 0.5;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

In this JS fiddle, you can see how the "yellow" element renders below the overlay. Is there any change possible while keeping the `.container` fixed?

http://jsfiddle.net/4ne83oa4/8/

Comment: Not possible unless you change the markup: http://jsfiddle.net/4ne83oa4/9/

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you must keep the markup as is, you can just play around with some pseudo classes for the `.container` class.

**Markup** stays the same, the **CSS** chages a bit like this: [check js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0L2zm8to/1/)

```
.container {
    position: fixed;
    background: red;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
}
.container:after,
.container:before{
    content: '';
    position: fixed;
 }
.container:after{
    z-index: -1;
    background: red;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;    
}
.container:before{
    z-index: 1;
    background: blue;
    opacity: 0.5;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
.inner {
    position: fixed;
    margin-top: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    background: yellow;
    height: 30px;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: Agreed, but I guess it comes down to what @DonnyP is trying to accomplish